# Existance of Linearly Independent generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Is it true that all $n\times n$ matrices $A$ admit $n$ generalized eigenvectors? Are they all linearly independent? Intuitively I know it's true over complex numbers but I could not find a rigorous proof.

I am doing linear systems of differential equations and I want to prove that for the system $x'=Ax$ it is always possible to find $n$ linearly independent solutions of the form:
$$
x=\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_ie^{\lambda t}t^{n-i}
$$
Where $\xi_i$ is a generalized evigenvector of rank $i$ with associated eigenvalue $\lambda$. I need to ensure that if $\lambda$ is a repeated eigenvalue of multiplicity $m$ then $m$ linearly independent solutions are associated with it. For insufficient eigenvalues, existence of higher rank generalized eigenvectors guarantees extra solutions because of the following property:
$$
A\xi_i=\xi_{i-1}+\lambda\xi_i \quad\text{which is analogous to}\quad [t^ne^{\lambda t}]'=t^{n-1}e^{\lambda t}+\lambda t^ne^{\lambda t}
$$
Geometrically, if the generalized eigenvectors are linearly independent, then we can express every point in terms of generalized eigenvectors. This explains why the solution is is a [degenerate node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF0mr.png) that curves towards the eigendirection.

Comment: Yes, *over the complex numbers*, where every matrix is similar to its [Jordan Normal Form](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Jordan_normal_form#Generalized_eigenvectors) by conjugating by the matrix whose columns form the basis of generalized eigenvectors. More [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Generalized_eigenvector) about generalized eigenvectors and examples of how to compute them.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the existence of Jordan normal form. For any $n \times n$ complex matrix $A$, a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$ made of generalized eigen vectors of $A$ exists. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Complex_matrices

Your idea of constructing solution to $x'=Ax$ using generalized eigen vectors is nice. So by above yes you can construct the solution to $x'=Ax$ although with complex values.